# Why is git ignoring my /bower_components folder?

Tags: git, bower, gitignore

Why is git ignoring my /bower_components folder? It will commit /bower_components/bootstrap, but none of the folders contents, or any of the other folders in bower_components.

```
git add --all
git commit -m "adding bootstrap"
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean

git clean -ndX                                 
Would remove App_Data/packages/NoGit.0.0.8/node_modules/nogit/node_modules/globa
l-tunnel/node_modules/                     

dir bower_components
Volume in drive C is BOOTCAMP
Volume Serial Number is 28B2-7D02

Directory of c:\Projects\Blog6\Publish\Latest\bower_components

10/31/2014  10:00 PM    <DIR>          .
10/31/2014  10:00 PM    <DIR>          ..
10/31/2014  10:00 PM    <DIR>          angular
10/31/2014  10:00 PM    <DIR>          angular-route
10/31/2014  10:46 PM    <DIR>          bootstrap
...
```

I created my own .gitignore file, just to see if it would help the issue. But it didn't.

```
# Compiled source # 
###################
*.com
*.pdb

# Packages #   
############
# it's better to unpack these files and commit the raw source
# git has its own built in compression methods
*.7z
*.dmg
*.gz
*.iso
*.jar
*.rar
*.tar
*.zip

# Logs and databases #
######################
*.log
*.sql
*.sqlite

# OS generated files #
######################
.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
ehthumbs.db
Thumbs.db
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild guess that except `bootstrap`, none of the folders under `bower_components` have any files in them(even if you go into their subfolders - you'll find only other folders, no files).

Git can not track folders - only files. The folder structure of the project is derived from the files it tracks - so if it tracked a file named `foo/bar` it knows to create the `foo` directory so it can put `bar` in it, but if `foo` was empty Git would simply ignore it.

If you have some empty directories that for whatever reason must be part of the repository, the convention is to put an empty file named `.gitkeep` in them.

Comment: For some reason the contents didn't copy over. THey shouldn't have been empty, but they were :( many thanks!